# Using AWS Lambda to copying S3 files to on-premise LAN folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, file, amazon-s3, transfer

**Problem:**
We need to perform a task under which we have to transfer all files ( CSV format) stored in AWS S3 bucket to a on-premise LAN folder using the Lambda functions. This will be a scheduled tasks which will be carried out after every 1 hour, and the file will again be transferred from S3 to on-premise LAN folder while replacing the existing ones. Size of these files is not large (preferably under few MBs).

I am not able to find out any AWS managed service to accomplish this task.

I am a newbie to AWS, any solution to this problem is most welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: There are multiple options, every having its pros and cons. Question - doesn it need to be a lambda fn? Is it bound to some event (S3 notification)? Or it is just a timer?

Comment: Hello @devfromfinland, Thanks for sharing this approach. Actually, I am looking for a solution by which I can push S3 files to on-premise folder automatically e.g. using some Lambda function.

Comment: It is never easy to push files to a computer, since computers are designed to limit access. (For example, you wouldn't want me pushing files onto your computer.) It is much easier to _pull_ files _into_ the instance. Would this be acceptable?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, Understand your point regrading pulling the files into the instance and its valid only. Actually, before this transfer for files, these files are being created in S3 bucket (in csv format) through lambda by extracting the query results from RDS instance. And once these files are created, they need to be placed under on-premise folder location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Actually, I am looking for a solution by which I can push S3 files to on-premise folder automatically

For that you need to make the on-premise network visible to the logic (lambda, whatever..) "pushing" the content. The default solution is using the [AWS site-to-site VPN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/VPC_VPN.html).

There are multiple [options for setting up the VPN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpn-connections.html), you could choose based on the needs.

Then the on-premise network will look just like another subnet.

However - VPN has its complexity and cost. In most of the cases it is much easier to "pull" data from the on-premise environment.

To sync data there are multiple options. For a managed service, I could point out the [S3 Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/) which based on your description sounds like an insane overkill.

Maybe you could start with a simple cron job (or a task timer if working with windows) and run a CLI command to [sync the S3 content](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) or just copy specified files.

Answer (score 0):

Check out S3 Sync, I think it will help you accomplish this task: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/sync.html#examples

To run any AWS CLI in your computer, you will need to setup credentials, and the setup account/roles should have permissions to do the task (e.g. access S3)
Check out AWS CLI setup here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html